# Star Rating for Salesforce Contact Objects individual records

Tags: salesforce

I want to rate the star by virtual out of 5 in Salesforce Contact Standard Objects for individual records and then need to store that star rating value in one Custom Object field. I don’t know how to do this. I am the new one for Salesforce development. Please guide me or give some relevant examples to do this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7rg6.png)

Comment: I have used this code for showing Star Rating in Virtual. But I don't know how to validate Star rating with Salesforce objects please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <apex:page standardcontroller="Contact" showHeader="true">

<style type="text/css">
.rating {
    float:left;
}

/* :not(:checked) is a filter, so that browsers that don’t support :checked don’t 
   follow these rules. Every browser that supports :checked also supports :not(), so
   it doesn’t make the test unnecessarily selective */
.rating:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
    clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    width:1em;
    padding:0 .1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:200%;
    line-height:1.2;
    color:#ddd;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #bbb, 2px 2px #666, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: '★ ';
}

.rating > input:checked ~ label {
    color: #f70;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #c60, 2px 2px #940, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: gold;
    text-shadow:1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating > input:checked + label:hover,
.rating > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
    color: #ea0;
    text-shadow:1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating > label:active {
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
    left:2px;
}
</style>

<fieldset class="rating" style="border:none;">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="5th level connection">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="4th level connection">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="3rd level connection">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="2nd level connection">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="1st level connection">1 star</label>
</fieldset>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I got the Star Rating virtually in Salesforce Objects detailed page but I need to update star rate value in Salesforce objects.